# How can I create windows application where I can read excel sheet and convert it in a specific format?

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, windows

How can I specify 6 columns and name them in `datagridview` so when I import an excel sheet with missing columns it adds the missing columns, keeps the content empty and arrange the columns based on what I specify in `datagridview`?
Note: column name does not change

For example I specify columns `A,B,C,D` in `datagridview`. The excel sheet has the same column name but some of them are missing for example `A,C`

This is what I did to import the excel sheet into the application

```
using ExcelDataReader;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace excelreaderdesktop
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fil = new OpenFileDialog();
            fil.ShowDialog();
            string path = fil.FileName.ToString();
            ExcelFileReader(path);
        }

        public void ExcelFileReader(string path)
        {
            var stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream);
            var result = reader.AsDataSet();
            var tables = result.Tables.Cast<DataTable>();
            foreach(DataTable table in tables)
            {
                dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First you will need to decide which Excel library you want to use to open and read the Excel file. There are numerous libraries to pick from. EPPlus is a popular library that works well. Interop is also an option. If you need this in a production environment, you should ask the server operators which library is acceptable. So, the first step is to figure out which library you want to use. After you have read the Excel file, then you can worry about setting the data into a grid.

Comment: What have you done so far? This is not a free coding service. Show a clear example of source to result then people may help. Also have a look on here for Q&A which may give you bits of code towards your goal.